# Image with comments send from Android in PHP

Tags: php, android, json, image

I want to send an image with some comments from an Android device to a PHP server. I want to make use of JSON to exchage data. I looked at many places, but I am not getting the right hint. Can anyone suggest some pointers to get this working with PHP?

I don't want to use base65 as it will increase the dataload and image size is also a probelm with this. Please suggest your thoughts and right approach to develop this.

My Android COde :

```
   // Building Parameters
                List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("description", description));
                params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("image","/sdcard/DCIM/android_1.png"));
// getting JSON Object       
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,"POST", params);

            // check log cat fro response
            Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());
// check for success tag
            try {
                int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

                if (success == 1) {
                    // successfully created product
                    Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AllProductsActivity.class);
                    startActivity(i);

                    // closing this screen
                    finish();
                } else {
                    // failed to create product
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Where as when I add image in it with multipart:

```
 MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
            try {
                reqEntity.addPart("name", new StringBody(name));
                reqEntity.addPart("Id", new StringBody(price));
                reqEntity.addPart("title",new StringBody(description));
                //reqEntity.addPart("pic", new FileBody(new File("/sdcard/DCIM/android_1.png")));

            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            Bitmap bitmap = null ;
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bos);
             byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();
             ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "/sdcard/android_1.png");
            reqEntity.addPart("pic", bab);
```

I am not sure how I can pass this multipart reqentitty with JSON :

// getting JSON Object
            JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_product,"POST", params);

and how I can read this as image in PHP. Without image PHP working code as below :

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();
$target_path1 = "uploads/";

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['description'])) {

    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    $description = $_POST['description'];    
//I have data from android here now but How I can read image here ?
```

So I have two question here :
1. How to pass the image as a part of JSONObject (first code working without image)
2.  How can I read this image back in PHP?

I would really appreciate any comments or suggestions .
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never used JSON to pass an image, only text, but u can use android to post informatoin through the use of HTTP. Check out this tutorial, it helped me http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/

Comment: we will try this, but I don't see how to send "Text" along with image ?

Comment: Well for that you will need to use JSON. Most of the work with what your trying to do with rely on PHP as opposed to android. What you need to do is pass the text with JSON, and the image as a post